# Why won't email generated within mvc 3 application send on live (release) version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email, smtp

I have set up an e-mail service within my mvc 3 application using Action Mailer.
Everything works great in development on local machine , tested the service by first sending email to my C drive, then using a 3rd party smtp server provider and then through a gmail account.
However when deployed to the server the e-mails stopped getting out.
Both ports 587 and 465 have being opened on the server and I ran short vb test script with similar setting to my Web.config file mailSettings to confirm email can be sent from the server.
Am I missing something from my mailsettings in Web config ?
Or is there other settings I need to check with regard to deployment with this email service ?

```
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465" userName="email@address.com" password="mypassword" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

When port 465 is used in both production and release versions the application just hangs. When port 587 is used production fires off the email no problem and release returns an error (custom error= Off) "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"